# GTK+-2.0 get window background pixmap

Tags: gtk, x11

### I'm looking for a way to store the current background pixmap of a window using GTK+-2.0

I have found this function: [`gdk_window_set_back_pixmap()`](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gdk/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-back-pixmap) that allows a pixmap to be set as the background, but I cannot find anything that lets me do the inverse - that is, get the background pixmap.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find such a function because there isn't any. From the [X Windows FAQ](http://ftp.x.org/contrib/faqs/x-faq-multipart/x-faq-7):

> Subject: 174)  *Can XGetWindowAttributes get a window's background
>   pixel/pixmap?*
>
> No.  Once set, the background pixel or pixmap of a window cannot be
>   re-read by clients.  The reason for this is that a client can create a
>   pixmap, set it to be the background pixmap of a window, and then free
>   the pixmap. The window keeps this background, but the pixmap itself is
>   destroyed.  If you're sure a window has a background pixel (not a
>   pixmap), you can use `XClearArea()` to clear a region to the background
>   color and then use `XGetImage()` to read back that pixel.  However, this
>   action alters the contents of the window, and it suffers from race
>   conditions with exposures. *[courtesy Dave Lemke of NCD and Stuart
>   Marks of Sun]*

Since GTK is a rather straightforward wrapper around X11 primitives, it doesn't offer much beyond what X11 has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest this method

- create child window of the same size, with following atributes

  - background pixmap is ParentRelative
  - GCTileStipXOrigin and GCTileStipYOrigin are zero
  - GCFillStyle is FillTiled
- do not map it
- clear it with XClearWindow
- grab its content with XGetImage

Might work :-)